# Filename as last argument to MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC controller with a single method which contains a few arguments, the last of which is a filename with an extension and it is this last argument which causes issues.

Say the format I wish to create is:

```
http://example.com/worker/90bef68f718a434bb588120e717fa29c/foo.txt
```

This URL will 404, however if I remove the period or add a trailing / then the handler is hit and executed normally.

Unfortunately the URL format I am trying to implement cannot accommodate either of these work arounds.

The route is defined as follows:

```
     routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Worker Handler",
        url: "worker/{guid}/{fileName}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Worker", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Some reading suggested changing the url template to include {fileName} to {*fileName}, however that too did nothing to fix this.

Comment: have you considered encoding file name before making url out of it? Like with using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx befo

Comment: Are you able to use other format of Url then I can suggest the solution. I would suggest that worker/{guid}/{fileName}/{fileextension}. This will solve your problem.

Comment: I would if I could... but can't. The URL format is set in stone and ends with a filename with an extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suggest two solution.

First Use route like this ( FileName and FileExtention in separate argument)

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Worker Handler",
        url: "worker/{guid}/{fileName}/{fileextention}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Worker", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Another solution is to add following thing in web.config.

```
 <system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Get Help from http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html

Route should be like this.

```
  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Worker Handler",
    url: "worker/{guid}/{fileName}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Worker", action = "Index" }
    );
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: The web.config change did it, thanks! Off hand do you know if there are any positive or negative implications of clearing out existing UrlRoutingModule-4.0 configurations?

Comment: Honestly I also have to go into deep for that in IIS. I am looking into that. At this moment I can tell you that It clear setting default by IIS then add same module again. I will update post over here.